# Python: re.sub with conditions not working

Tags: python, replace

```
        Foo_foo = column3 [3]
        Bar_bar = column4 [4]
        Content = column5 [5]

        Foo_foo_replacement = "FOOFOOFOOFOOFOO"
        Bar_bar_replacement = "BARBARBARBARBAR"

        if (len(Foo_foo) > 3):
            re.sub(Foo_foo, Foo_foo_replacement, Content)
        if (len(Bar_bar) > 3):
            re.sub(last_name, Bar_bar_replacement , Content)
```

The script above is supposed to find `Foo_foo`,`Bar_bar` in my `Content` and replace it with `FOOFOOFOOFOOFOO`,`BARBARBARBARBAR` however I cannot get it to work. I have tried with a space between the comma and the target(s), matching cases, etc. I cannot get it to work. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the content of `Foo_foo`, `Bar_bar` and `Content`?

Comment: You need to assign the results to something.  You're creating new strings, then dropping them on the floor.

Comment: http://rextester.com/NBN58988 works

Comment: @TomKarzes geeze.. newb.. ha, thanks I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tom Karzes for pointing out my mistake. The following works.

```
    Foo_foo = column3 [3]
    Bar_bar = column4 [4]
    Content = column5 [5]

    Foo_foo_replacement = "FOOFOOFOOFOOFOO"
    Bar_bar_replacement = "BARBARBARBARBAR"

    if (len(Foo_foo) > 3):
        content = re.sub(Foo_foo, Foo_foo_replacement, Content)
    if (len(Bar_bar) > 3):
        content = re.sub(last_name, Bar_bar_replacement , Content)
```